# What's the best practice for connecting information of two entities?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony

It's a bit difficult for me to put my questions in words, but I'll try.

I have two entities. One is called Product the other Sale. Each product has field definining the number of available items of this product. Each sale has a field stating the number of sold items of one product. Product to Sale is a OneToMany-Relationship.

Now if I want to find out if a product has sold out, I need to create a function which substracts the total number of sold items from the initial availability number of the product. Something like `function getAvailableQuantity()`.

My question is: Where do I place this method?
I am tempted to put it in the Product Repository - but since this method needs to access the Sales entity this is against Dependency Injection. However, placing it in the controller seems like an unnecessary detour as I am losing the possibility of calling `{{ product.getAvailableQuantity }}` in Twig templates.

What is the way to go?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest subtracting the sold items right away from `Product::available_items`. This would resolve the issue right away, because `Product::available_items` would always reflect the number of available items.

**Method no. 1**

Subtract `Sale::quantity` from `Product` right away.

```php
public function setProduct(ProductInterface $product)
{
    $new_count = $product->getAvailableItems() - $this->getQuantity();
    $product->setAvailableItems($new_count);

    $this->product = $product;
}
```

You'd also have to do the subtracting in all the controllers that might change the available item count.

---

**Method no. 2**

Personally, I would actually favor this method over the first one, because it keeps the logic in a single place and generally results in shorter controllers. In addition, my entities are usually long enough without all the domain logic.

Assuming `Sale` has a reference to a `Product`, I'd put the logic into a service (an entity-specific entitymanager, e.g [`UserManager`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManagerInterface.php). It'd be called `SaleManager` in our case). The method in it would look something similar to:

```php
public function updateSale(SaleInterface $sale, $flush = true)
{
    $product   = $sale->getProduct();
    $new_count = $product->getAvailableItems() - $sale->getQuantity();

    if ($new_count < 0) {
        throw new NegativeQuantityException();
    }

    $product->setAvailableItems($new_count);

    $this->em->persist($sale);

    if (true === $flush) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

I didn't touch the issue of what would happen if you were to remove a `Sale` from a `Product` or switch a `Product in a sale`, but you must certainly consider this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I see correctly both of your methods end up in having redundant data. I am not sure if this is the way I want to go as I see a chance for inconsistent data in the future.

Comment: @sprain I'm guessing you're seeing the subtraction as redundant? In my view, there are 2 important values: 1) total item count without product item counts; 2) actual item count. The first approach would be to store the total item count and subtract product item counts to get the actual count, whereas my method would store the actual item count and add product counts to get the total item count. Both are essentially the same. Where do you see the chance of inconsistent data?

Comment: What I see as redundant data is the fact that Product::available_items is being saved to the database. This is something I do not wish for in my case as the total number of available items may be increased anytime - regardless how many items have been sold already. By saving available_items to the database I would have to keep track of two numbers - giving chance for inconsistent data.

Comment: @sprain hmm, I think we're misunderstanding each other. I'm suggesting to subtract the number of sold items from the initial number of items right away rather than doing it every time you want to know how many items you've got left. You probably need that number more anyway and should you need the initial count, it would be the sum of sold item count of each `Sale` plus items left.

Comment: Thanks for the respose. I think I do understand your point and you are right that this usually makes sense even though not in my project right now. But I see how you handle it. Another question has rosen though: I tried to follow your solution, created a service in DependendyInjection folder and got it working. However, I seem not to be able to access EntityManager there. How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: @sprain You can pass the entity manager by injecting a service `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`. Here's an [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container) service.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I place this method?

Consider creating a ProductSalesManager service into which you inject the entity manager.  From a controller you would have something like:

```
$productSalesManager = $this->get(product_sales.manager);
$products = $productSalesManager->getProductsWithAvailableQuantity();
```

Now you can put your logic in the manager without worrying about which repository it happens to be in.  It also decouples your controller from Doctrine itself.

And I'm not so sure maintaining current inventory in the product itself is such a good idea but that is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As the available quantity bellows to the Product, I think the work has to be done by the Product Entity.

If you use Doctrine, it has generated the function `addSale` in your Product Entity ( the name depend on how you define the relation). I should change this function to make the calculation.
Assuming the field in your product entity is named `available_quantity` and the field in your Sale Entity is named `items_number`:

```
public function addSale ( $sale )
{
    $this->setAvailableQuantity($this->getAvailableQuantity() - $sale->getItemsNumber());
    $this->sales[] = $sale;
}
```

Then in your controller you add the sale to the product:

```
// get the product
$product = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
    ->find($id);
// build your Sale object
$sale = new Sale();
...
// add it to the product
$product->addSale($sale);

// save all
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($sale);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

In your template you can get the available quantity of your product:

```
{{ product.availableQuantity }}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll put some thought into it and compare it with the other suggestions. Thanks!